# seekTo(milisecs); in android MediaPlayer giving improper value for getCurrentPosition()

Tags: android, media-player

I am using `MediaPlayer` in my application. And one `Timer` running for getting current playing position.
When I am trying to call `seekTo(0);`, it's giving  the current position 0 then giving old current position, after that it's giving proper value.

Comment: Add the code to your problem.

Comment: to get current position use `player.getCurrentPosition()`

Comment: I am using getCurrentPosition() inside a timer.Lets consider Player is in 20th milisec,call seekTo(0) giving 0 for  getCurrentPosition() again 21,22 then starts with 0,1,2,3.........

Answer (score 1):

This is because `seekTo` is asynchronous operation. I.e. the call `seekTo()` completes immediately, but the actual seek operation can be executed after several seconds (the delay depends on video, seekTo position, internet bandwidth and etc.).